# Google Maps in Android app crashes

Tags: android, google-maps

In attempting to add a map to an Android app I encountered an error to the extent of:

> 04-15 17:36:42.036: E/AndroidRuntime(28534):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{xxx}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file
>   line #7: Error inflating class fragment

I have read over numerous posts, and articles on what the problem might be and have tried any number of suggestions from:

- [verifying uses-library in Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957117/27860)
- Adding the Google SDK (as opposed to the Android SDK).
- Extending FragmentActivity (as opposed to Activity).
- Setting up API Keys and adding them to the Manifest.

However, nothing changes the results. The app still crashes when trying to launch that activity, with the same error message.

In an attempt to narrow things down I downloaded the sample application from [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/google-maps-in-android-application-with-new-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-supportmapfragment/), but it crashes with the exact same error message.

Being relatively new to Android, the above sample looked fine, but with it crashing it's hard to tell where the error is. The complete stack trace is can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jwhitehorn/5391998).

I am developing this on a Nexus 4, running Android 4.2.

I would have assumed that the referenced sample app would have at least worked. Am I wrong? Is there something wrong with the sample I've been referencing?

Comment: Can we see the xml file? Seems to be related to the error

Comment: @TimCastelijns, the full source can be found at the bottom of this post -> http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/google-maps-in-android-application-with-new-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-supportmapfragment/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to my detailed step by step tutorial for using google android Map v2 on Android Virtual Device(Emulator) Android 4.2 http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Specifically, make sure that the reference to `google-play-services_lib` can be resolved. If it cannot be resolved, the application will compile and launch successfully up to the point where it actually needs to display the map. Then it will crash.

- Right click on the project in Eclipse, and select Properties.
- On the left select "Android"
- Ensure that `google-play-services_lib` has a green check mark next to it on the right under Library.

If it has a red "X" or is missing entirely, the reference will need to be re-added.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll dig into this in the morning and let you know what I discover.

Comment: That lead me in the right direction. It turned out to be I wasn't referencing `google-play-services_lib` and the sample was, but it couldn't find it. And, instead of a compiler error, it just borked during runtime.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer to reflect my findings? That way, when I accept it, it'll be more obvious to future readers what the exact solution ways.